# What is definition of "corresponding angle"?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, education

This is a pedagogical question in high school context, regarding "corresponding angle":

The question is-

> To share the knowledge of corresponding angles one needs to consider
>
> - a pair of parallel straight lines only
> - a pair of parallel straight lines and a common transversal
> - a pair of parallel straight lines (may not be parallel) and a common transversal
> - a pair of intersecting straight lines

---

To my opinion both the $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ are correct according to the "exact" statement of the question.

**Definition 1:** If we take a pair of parallel straight lines and a common transversal, then the "corresponding angles" are also "congruent",

however,

**Definition 2:** If we consider pair of non-parallel straight lines and a common transversal, then the resulting "corresponding" angles do not become congruent.

Is there any book or literature where, only the author considered only the **Definition 1** for corresponding angles ?

Thanks

Comment: Corresponding angles are usually defined for a pair of lines (not necessarily parallel) cut by a transversal. Never seen a different definition.